# SQLITE user-defined functions in Lisp

Tags: sqlite, lisp, common-lisp

In SQLITE there is a possibility to relatively easily create User-Defined Functions and Aggregates in (extension) languages such as C, Perl, Python and others. Is there also such possibility using common-lisp as SQLITE language extension?  I know there are libraries like cl-sqlite and plain-odbc but they don't seem to offer this possibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I wrote [cl-sqlite](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-sqlite/), I hadn't thought about user-defined functions.

But it's actually pretty easy. It just takes to define callbacks, foreign functions and wrap them in lispy interface. I guess I'll add this feature to cl-sqlite soon.

Comment: Thanks. I am glad it wouldn't be difficult. Actually meanwhile I wrote a C code that uses sqlite3_exec and in the callback I embedded some ECL (lisp implementation) C functions like ecl_cons(ecl_cstring_to_base_string_or_nil(p_fields[i]),...
and call that in ECL using ffi:c-inline and ffi:clines. Then of course I could use the sqlite3_create_function in the C file on the C coded user-defined function. But in the updated cl-sqlite I   believe it will be easier because the user will define the user-defined function in CL without getting too involved with the C code (maybe only through the CFFI).